# Problem while setting jad with Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, jad

I am using jad to decompile my java class files through Eclipse. I have installed net.sf.jadclipse_3.3.0.jar plugin for Eclipse

- I put the jar in the Eclipse plugins directory.
- Next I have downloaded the jad windows plugin (jadretro-win32-x86-jcgo) for my Windows 7.
- Next I have started Eclipse and provided the path for the jadretro.exe in Eclipse.

But when i am trying to decompile my class files, its showing the error message -:
/*jadclipse*/
//Error!

Can someone please help ? I am using Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 1):

i hope you are not trying to view your class files (for which you have the source code). Jad throws the error

/*Jadclipse*/
//Error!

Pls try to view an OOTB jar or an imported jar

Comment: Why does jadclipse only work with OOTB jar files, but not any arbitary jar files.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should specify the path to jad.exe instead.

Comment: The exe file that I am using is named - jadretro.exe. I have specified this path. Wont this work ?

Comment: I think, no. You need to take the jad.exe binary (for example, from [here](http://www.varaneckas.com/sites/default/files/jad/jad158g.win.zip)).